# error while creating simple dictionary: 'dict' object is not callable

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to create a simple dictionary and want it to be printed as below:

```
Dict = dict({1:'geeks',2:'for',3:'geeks'})
print(Dict)
```

But, this is throwing an unexpected error as below:

```
Dict = dict({1:'geeks',2:'for',3:'geeks'})
print(Dict)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>   Dict = dict({1:'geeks',2:'for',3:'geeks'})
>
> TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: Probably you were assigning a dictionary you have created before to the name `dict`, shadowing the built-in `dict` type.

Comment: Looks like you've used `dict` as a variable name somewhere in your code.

Comment: You've name some variable dict. Name it in some other say. Also `{1:'geeks',2:'for',3:'geeks'}` is already a dict. No need for `dict(...)`